# how to access RichTextBox from one xaml file to another xaml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters, richtextbox

I am making a text editor and i have used `RichTextBox`. The tool bar is in another `user control` . When i am using editing commands like subscript , the same should be responded to the `RichTextBox` but i am not getting `richTextBox` name in another `user control`. Though i have tried with `get` and `set` and  by directly passing the `obj`. But i was not able to get the name of the field .

```
 <RichTextBox x:Name="body" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsTab="True"
                         Grid.Row="1" ></RichTextBox>
```

and the user control is

```
 <local:Hidden_bar Visibility="Visible" ComboBox.SelectionChanged="Toolbar_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

The class `Hidden_bar` needs `RichTextBox`  instance so that changes can be made on them but i am not able to get that instance in `local:Hidden_bar` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a static method in your `MainClass`:

```
static public RichTextBox rich;
```

and assign your `RichTextBox` to it, complete code for your `MainClass` is:

```
public partial class MainClass : Form
    {
        public MainClass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rich = this.richTextBox1;  //assign in the constructor
        }
        static public RichTextBox rich;
    }
```

Now you can call `MainClass.rich` and to get `text`, call `MainClass.rich.Text`.